# Sorting HTML table using addEventListener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table, toggle, addeventlistener

I am trying to sort HTML table using addEventListener in my JavaScript, by pushing any table column header. It basically works, but only either ascending or descending order.
It should work as a toggle; when you push the same column header again, the sort order should change as descending.

I am quite a beginner so I do not know how to make element.addEventListener function to activate my sortTable and reverseTable functions in turns while pushing the same column header.

I guess the problem is in this block, as the addEventListener takes in account only either sortTable function or reverseTable function, depending on which one is the latter one in the list. In this case, the reverseTable function, so it sorts in descending order and only once:

```
table.querySelectorAll('th') // get all the table header elements
  .forEach((element, columnNo)=>{ // add a click handler for each 
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
        sortTable(table, columnNo); //call a function which sorts the table by a given column number
        reverseTable(table,columnNo); //call a function to sort in reverse order
    })
})
```

The whole code with table data is here:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table'); //get the table to be sorted

table.querySelectorAll('th') // get all the table header elements
  .forEach((element, columnNo)=>{ // add a click handler for each 
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
        sortTable(table, columnNo); //call a function which sorts the table by a given column number
  reverseTable(table,columnNo); //call a function to sort in reverse order
    })
})
  
  function sortTable(table, sortColumn){
  // get the data from the table cells
  const tableBody = table.querySelector('tbody')
  const tableData = table2data(tableBody);
  // sort the extracted data
  tableData.sort((a, b)=>{
    if(a[sortColumn] > b[sortColumn]){
      return 1;
    }
    return -1;
   })
   
   //put the sorted data back into the table
  data2table(tableBody, tableData); 
}

function reverseTable(table, sortColumn){
  // get the data from the table cells
  const tableBody = table.querySelector('tbody')
  const tableData = table2data(tableBody);
  // sort the extracted data
  tableData.reverse((a, b)=>{
    if(a[sortColumn] > b[sortColumn]){
      return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  })
  
  // put the sorted data back into the table
  data2table(tableBody, tableData);
}
   

// this function gets data from the rows and cells 
// within an html tbody element
function table2data(tableBody){
  const tableData = []; // create the array that'll hold the data rows
  tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr')
    .forEach(row=>{  // for each table row...
      const rowData = [];  // make an array for that row
      row.querySelectorAll('td')  // for each cell in that row
        .forEach(cell=>{
          rowData.push(cell.innerText);  // add it to the row data
        })
      tableData.push(rowData);  // add the full row to the table data 
    });
  return tableData;
}

// this function puts data into an html tbody element
function data2table(tableBody, tableData){
  tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr') // for each table row...
    .forEach((row, i)=>{  
      const rowData = tableData[i]; // get the array for the row data
      row.querySelectorAll('td')  // for each table cell ...
        .forEach((cell, j)=>{
          cell.innerText = rowData[j]; // put the appropriate array element into the cell
        })
      tableData.push(rowData);
    });
}
```

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Age</th</tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>John</td><td>Smith</td><td>62</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dylan</td><td>Jones</td><td>37</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Alan</td><td>Shearer</td><td>55</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Ringo</td><td>Starr</td><td>52</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I solved your problem by adding attributes to `<th>` tags, now they save their state and on next click, we know what to do, also I change arrow function(name() => {}) to regular function(function name(){}) to have access to `this` for more details of their difference please read [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256) article, so here's your code, I hope I helped you and it works as expected

*EDIT: as @user4642212 mentioned in comments [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) are much more convenient way to solve this problem so I edited my actual code

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table'); //get the table to be sorted

table.querySelectorAll('th') // get all the table header elements
  .forEach((element, columnNo) => { // add a click handler for each 
    element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      const isReverse = (this.dataset.reverse == 'true')
      this.dataset.reverse = !isReverse
      console.log(isReverse)
      if (isReverse) sortTable(table, columnNo); //call a function which sorts the table by a given column number
      else reverseTable(table, columnNo); //call a function to sort in reverse order
    })
  })

function sortTable(table, sortColumn) {
  // get the data from the table cells
  const tableBody = table.querySelector('tbody')
  const tableData = table2data(tableBody);
  // sort the extracted data
  tableData.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[sortColumn] > b[sortColumn]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return -1;
  })

  //put the sorted data back into the table
  data2table(tableBody, tableData);
}

function reverseTable(table, sortColumn) {
  // get the data from the table cells
  const tableBody = table.querySelector('tbody')
  const tableData = table2data(tableBody);
  // sort the extracted data
  tableData.reverse((a, b) => {
    if (a[sortColumn] > b[sortColumn]) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  })

  // put the sorted data back into the table
  data2table(tableBody, tableData);
}


// this function gets data from the rows and cells 
// within an html tbody element
function table2data(tableBody) {
  const tableData = []; // create the array that'll hold the data rows
  tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr')
    .forEach(row => { // for each table row...
      const rowData = []; // make an array for that row
      row.querySelectorAll('td') // for each cell in that row
        .forEach(cell => {
          rowData.push(cell.innerText); // add it to the row data
        })
      tableData.push(rowData); // add the full row to the table data 
    });
  return tableData;
}

// this function puts data into an html tbody element
function data2table(tableBody, tableData) {
  tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr') // for each table row...
    .forEach((row, i) => {
      const rowData = tableData[i]; // get the array for the row data
      row.querySelectorAll('td') // for each table cell ...
        .forEach((cell, j) => {
          cell.innerText = rowData[j]; // put the appropriate array element into the cell
        })
      tableData.push(rowData);
    });
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-reverse="true">Name</th>
      <th data-reverse="true">Surname</th>
      <th data-reverse="true">Age</th</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>62</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dylan</td>
      <td>Jones</td>
      <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alan</td>
      <td>Shearer</td>
      <td>55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ringo</td>
      <td>Starr</td>
      <td>52</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use [`data` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead.

Comment: oh thanks, tbh I never heard of them but they are very convenient way

Comment: One additional question: as in the final version I am creating the table dynamically, so how should I add the "data-reverse" attributes for the headers? Currently the dynamic code for creating headers is done by doc.createElement(th). So how can I fit the data-reverse attributes on top?

Comment: I think you can use `element.setAtribute()` method

Comment: Like this?: var element = doc.createElement("th"); element.setAttribute(data-reverse,"true");

Comment: Not working. Here is what I basically did:                                    
```addRow(thead, "th"); 
    fragment.appendChild(thead); 

function addRow(dom, tag) {
    for(j=1;j<rowArray.length;j++){
    var el = doc.createElement(tag);
 el.setAttribute(data-reverse,"true");
    el.innerHTML = rowArray[j];
    tr.appendChild(el);
    dom.appendChild(tr);
  }
 }```



So the issue is most probably in 
```el.innerHTML = rowArray[j];``` but how to fix that?